# Using _id from MongoDb as ID in Loopback 4

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback4

I want use the _id(ObjectId) create as unique key on mongoDB as the id from my model.

(with a sql database i coult use the auto increment from database to control this)

The model where is the attribute:

```
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  _id?: number;
```

But when I make a find using the URL return this:

```
   {
        "_id": null,
        "name": "sadsadsadasdasdsa",
        "email": "string"
    }
```

And in mongoDB:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKtJU.png)

How can i retrive the _id?

Comment: I suggest you to change `type: 'number',` to `type: 'string',`  in your model. Also change `_id?: number;` to `_id?: string;`

Answer (score 1):

The ID property must use `type: string`:

```js
@model({
  settings: {
    strictObjectIDCoercion: true
}})
export class User extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
  })
  id: string;
...
}
```

### Further reading

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/MongoDB-connector.html#model-scope